# format date in groovy and save in desired format with milliseconds

Tags: java, date, groovy, simpledateformat

I'm trying to get a full date with milliseconds.

I tried following

```
        Date callTime = new Date();

        String formattedDate = callTime.format('MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS');

        println "formattedDate : " + formattedDate;

        def saveThisDate = new Date().parse("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS", formattedDate);

        println "saveThisDate : " + saveThisDate;
```

And it gave output as following

```
formattedDate : 12/22/2014 15:51:47.427
saveThisDate : Mon Dec 22 15:51:47 IST 2014
```

where the `formattedDate` gives correct output but I've to save it in a date so i tried doing `saveThisDate` . But it doesn't save milliseconds.

Where I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Dates are just dates, they don't have a format.  You only give a data type a format when you convert it to a String.  Create a String from the Date and give it the format you need.

Answer (score 1):

It saves, You need to format it as well:

```
Date callTime = new Date();

String formattedDate = callTime.format('MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS');

println "formattedDate : " + formattedDate;

def saveThisDate = new Date().parse("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS", formattedDate);

println "saveThisDate : " + saveThisDate.format('MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS');
```

Answer (score 1):

if you don't do additional formatting, the `saveThisDate` is printed out in default date format (depends on locale of your machine) and it doesn't include ms.

follow Opal's example